# adding : notation to C# for indexing into arrays

Tags: c#, .net

I use to use IDL and MatLab in college and now that I have been working for some years I miss the : notation for indexing into arrays. e.g.

```
arrray[1:5]
```

which would return an array from elements from 1 to 5. Another example is:

```
stringVar.Split(")".ToCharArray())[1:*]
```

which would return an array of strings skipping over the first element.

**Has anyone seen a way to shoe-horn : notation this into C#?**

I have seen it in some interpreted languages and Perl or Python, can't remember.

**I wonder if this could be done with some operator overriding?**

Comment: C# does not support the notation or customer operators in the way you describe. On the other hand, F# <i>does</i> support array slicing and is somewhat similar to MATLAB as well, so it might be a good .NET alternative to C#.

Comment: That is a much better solution then fighting the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently implemented in the BCL.  The best way to add this on would be via an extension method.  For instance, here's a quick and dirty example (not fully featured).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string range) {
  var arr = range.Split(':');
  var start = Int32.Parse(arr[0]);
  if ( arr[1] == "*" ) {
    return enmuerable.Skip(start);
  } else {
    var end = Int32.Parse(arr[1]);
    return enumerable.Skip(start).Take(end-start);
  }
}
```

Then you could do

```
strVar.GetRange("1:*");  // Skip first element take rest
strVar.GetRange("1:5");  // Skip first element next 5
```

**Note**: I'm not familiar with Matlab syntax at all so I'm not sure if I implemented it to the proper specs but hopefully it gets the general idea across.

Comment: I wonder how it's better than having an overloaded method with two parameters (and using some kind of constant in place of *).

Comment: @Mehrdad, I think it's much better to do as you describe.  Mainly I just wanted to demonstrate how one could implement such a feature if it was really important.

Comment: Nice!  I went down the wrong path, I had activators and loops ... ugly. :)

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically, there's nothing like this in C# and can't be done with operator overloading. Basically, per C# spec, the lexical analyzer will consider that a syntax error. You could use a third party custom preprocessor to make it work.

`ArraySegment` structure, however, *semantically* does a similar thing.

If you really love this stuff, consider looking at Python (or IronPython if you want it on .NET platform).

Answer (score 0):

There is no language syntax for this, but if you're using 3.5 you could use some IEnumerable extension methods to as you say "shoe-horn" it in:

```
int offset = 1;
int num = 5;
int[] array = new int[5];
var collection = array.Skip(offset).Take(num - offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own two-dimensional index accessor, and have `-1` represent `*`:

```
public object[] this[int x, int y]
{
    get {/* implement get logic here */}
    set {/* implement set logic here */}
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
object[] slice = myArray[1, 5];
object[] slice2 = myArray[1, -1];
```

I don't recommend it though... I believe you should conform yourself to the language you are using, not the other way around. There are methods and classes that do the same thing, see the other answers.